# Getting the siblings of a node with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Is there a way to find a specific value in a node and then return all its sibling values?

For example, I would like to find find the `id` node that contains ID 5678 and then get the email address and all images associated with ID 5678.

```
Nokogiri::XML.parse(File.open('info.xml'))
```

Here's a sample XML file.

```xml
<xmlcontainer>
  <details>
    <id>1234</id>
    <email>sdfsdf@sdasd.com</email>
    <image>images/1.jpg</image>
    <image>images/2.jpg</image>
    <image>images/3.jpg</image>
  </details>
  <details>
    <id>5678</id>   
    <email>zzzz@zzz.com</email>
    <image>images/4.jpg</image>
    <image>images/5.jpg</image>
  </details>
  <details>
    <id>9011</id>   
    <email>aaaa@aaa.com</email>
    <image>images/6.jpg</image>
    <image>images/7.jpg</image>
  </details>
</xmlcontainer>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse(File.open('info.xml'))
details = doc.css('details').find{|node| node.css('id').text == "5678"}
email = details.css('email').text # => "zzzz@zzz.com"
images = details.css('image').map(&:text) # => ["images/4.jpg", "images/5.jpg"]
```

**Update:** There are shorter, arguably better, ways to grab the `details` node you want:

```
details = doc.at('details:has(id[text()="5678"])')
```

or

```
details = doc.search('id[text()="5678"] ~ *')
```

Those are both courtesy of pguardiario.

Comment: You might tighten that up by replacing `select{}.first` with `find{}` or you can get at the details node more directly with `doc.at('details:has(id[text()="5678"])')`

Comment: @pguardiario So many ways to search a document! Thanks for the tips!

Comment: You're welcome! also in that case xpath might actually be simpler: `doc.at('//id[text()="5678"]/..')`

Comment: Useful indeed. ".." is covered in http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev *facepalm*

Answer (score 7):

You can use `~`, which is the css general sibling selector:

```
doc.search('id[text()="5678"] ~ *').map &:text
#=> ["zzzz@zzz.com", "images/4.jpg", "images/5.jpg"]
```

It's a little bit weird to use css with xml but it's so much easier to look at (than xpath).

Comment: Very good syntax `'id[text()="5678"] ~ *'`. First time I found basically the part `XPATH` like `[text()="5678"]`. Where have you seen such trick? :) If possible explain the the search expression please.

Comment: The `[text()="5678"]` is not standard css but nokogiri allows it. The rest is just css. `~ *` means any sibling element

Comment: +1 "It's a little bit weird to use css with xml but it's so much easier to look at (than xpath)." I agree, and I'm glad Nokogiri gives us that option. CSS is usually a lot more readable.

Comment: "The [text()="5678"] is not standard css but nokogiri allows it." I haven't checked, but I suspect it's an extension to CSS pulled in from Nokogiri's implementation of jQuery's CSS accessors.

Comment: Actually, jQuery has a function called contains but there's no way to easily match exact text.

Comment: I agree that it's weird to use CSS with XML. It's a different domain altogether. Then again, I did XSLT for several years and thus XPath is more natural to me than CSS.