# CSS/Xpath sibling selector in Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, css-selectors, nokogiri

I have [the following XML tree](http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?id=PMC1637560&db=pmc) and need to get out the first name and surname only for the `contrib` tags with child `xref` nodes of `ref-type` `"corresp"`.

```
<pmc-articleset>
 <article>
  <front>
    <article-meta>
      <contrib-group>
        <contrib contrib-type="author">
          <name>
            <surname>Wereszczynski</surname>
            <given-names>Jeff</given-names>
          </name>
          <xref rid="aff1" ref-type="aff"/>
        </contrib>
        <contrib contrib-type="author">
          <name>
            <surname>Andricioaei</surname>
            <given-names>Ioan</given-names>
          </name>
          <xref rid="aff1" ref-type="aff"/>
          <xref ref-type="corresp" rid="cor1">*</xref>
        </contrib>
      </contrib-group>
    </article-meta>
  </front>
</article>
</pmc-articleset>
```

I saw "[Getting the siblings of a node with Nokogiri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828178/getting-the-siblings-of-a-node-with-nokogiri)" which points out the CSS sibling selectors that can be used in Nokogiri, but, following the example given, my code gives siblings indiscriminately.

```
require "Net/http"
require "nokogiri"
    url = "http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?id=PMC1637560&db=pmc"
    xml_data = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url)).body
    parsedoc = Nokogiri::XML.parse(xml_data)
    corrdetails = parsedoc.at('contrib:has(xref[text()="*"])')
    puts surname = corrdetails.xpath( "//surname" ).text
    puts givennames = corrdetails.xpath("//given-names").text

=> WereszczynskiAndricioaei
=> JeffIoan
```

I only want the sibling node under the condition that `<xref ref-type="corresp">*</>` , that is an output of:

```
=> Andricioaei
=> Ioan
```

I've currently implemented this without referring to `ref-type` but rather selecting the asterisk within the `xref` tag (either is appropriate).

Comment: I know nothing about Nokogiri, but the relevant XPath might be `//name[following-sibling::xref[@ref-type="corresp"]]/concat(given-names, " ", surname)`.

Comment: is that xpath 1.0 ? nokogiri can't use 2.0 and I wasn't aware those sorts of selectors were in 1.0, would be great if I were wrong...

Comment: I don't *think* there's anything in that expression that wasn't supported in XPath 1.0. `following-sibling::` and `concat` are both in the spec.

Comment: I'm getting an error that there's an excess `)` now, I don't see how - `puts corrdetails.xpath("//name[following-sibling::xref[@ref-type="corresp"]]")`

Comment: Presumably you need to escape the `"` in the query. BTW, your XML is invalid. You have `</article>` but no `<article>`. This may be a copy-paste error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is actually with your XPath for getting the the surname and given name, i.e., the XPath is incorrect for the lines:

```
puts surname = corrdetails.xpath( "//surname" ).text
puts givennames = corrdetails.xpath("//given-names").text
```

Starting the XPath with `//` means to look for the node *anywhere* in the document. You only want to look within the `corrdetails` node, which means the XPath needs to start with a dot, e.g., `.//`.

Change the two lines to:

```
puts surname = corrdetails.xpath( ".//surname" ).text
puts givennames = corrdetails.xpath(".//given-names").text
```