# How to get siblings' child according to specific defined sibling content

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I need to find the best method to gather writer and artist information from the following XML data. The `comic` node appears multiple times and includes data for a single comic book.

I can't grab the appropriate person according to their job function, writer, artist, etc. There are sometimes multiple writers and artists of each comic book. My plan is to add/append each to a List.

So, for this single comic book, I need to get all the writers' and artists' display name, but the job function (e.g. writer) is a sibling of the persons name.

Here is what I have, but doesn't work:

```
writer = []
penciler = []
doc.xpath('//comic').each do |main_element|
 main_element.xpath("mainsection/credits/credit/role[@id='dfWriter']").each do |n|
    writer << n.xpath('person/displayname').text
  end
  main_element.xpath("mainsection/credits/credit/role[@id='dfPenciler']").each do |n|
    penciler << n.xpath('person/displayname').text
  end
end

p "Writer(s): ",writer
p "Penciler(s): ",penciler
```

This is the XML file/data:

```
<comic>
  <id>3398</id>
  <index>195</index>
  <mainsection>
    <title>Mind Games</title>
    <myrating>0</myrating>
    <myrating>
      <displayname>0</displayname>
      <sortname>0</sortname>
    </myrating>
    <pagecount>32</pagecount>
    <credits>
      <credit>
        <role id="dfWriter">Writer</role>
        <roleid>dfWriter</roleid>
        <person>
          <displayname>Will Pfeifer</displayname>
          <sortname>Pfeifer, Will</sortname>
          <lastname>Pfeifer</lastname>
          <firstname>Will</firstname>
        </person>
      </credit>
      <credit>
        <role id="dfWriter">Writer</role>
        <roleid>dfWriter</roleid>
        <person>
          <displayname>John Byrne</displayname>
          <sortname>Byrne, John</sortname>
          <lastname>Byrne</lastname>
          <firstname>John</firstname>
        </person>
      </credit>
      <credit>
        <role id="dfPenciler">Penciller</role>
        <roleid>dfPenciler</roleid>
        <person>
          <displayname>John Byrne</displayname>
          <sortname>Byrne, John</sortname>
          <lastname>Byrne</lastname>
          <firstname>John</firstname>
        </person>
      </credit>
    </credits>
  </mainsection>
</comic>
```

The code I have does not give me the desired results. I found "[Getting the siblings of a node with Nokogiri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828178/getting-the-siblings-of-a-node-with-nokogiri)" but I need to iterate and grab each sibling.

I can either search by `<roleid>dfWriter</roleid>` or `<role id="dfWriter">Writer</role>` as they are the same.

My expected output would be:

```
Writer(s): Will Pfeifer, John Byrne 
Penciler(s): John Byrne
```

Comment: The XML doesn't appear to be consistent with your code. You show `comic` as the root node, but `//comic` isn't how we'd search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XPath [`following-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPath/Axes/following-sibling) axis for this purpose assuming the target element always located *after* `role` :

```
doc.xpath('//comic').each do |main_element|
 main_element.xpath("mainsection/credits/credit/role[@id='dfWriter']").each do |n|
    writer << n.xpath('following-sibling::person/displayname').text
  end
  main_element.xpath("mainsection/credits/credit/role[@id='dfPenciler']").each do |n|
    penciler << n.xpath('following-sibling::person/displayname').text
  end
end
```

Or you can just iterate through `credit` instead of `role` in the first place :

```
doc.xpath('//comic').each do |main_element|
 main_element.xpath("mainsection/credits/credit[role/@id='dfWriter']").each do |n|
    writer << n.xpath('person/displayname').text
  end
  main_element.xpath("mainsection/credits/credit[role/@id='dfPenciler']").each do |n|
    penciler << n.xpath('person/displayname').text
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I was looking for. Do you have any recommended reading for such issues?

Comment: Learn XPath. I started with [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp), then [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath) and the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/). And a lot of playing around with XPath in an XPath tester (such as [xpathtester](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath) or [xpatheval](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/))

Comment: I didn't realize how much of a beast Xpath is. Thanks

Comment: Nokogiri lets us use XPath and CSS, for good reasons. CSS is much easier to read, and ties well to dealing with HTML, however CSS also lacks the depth that XPath has, so learning both is good. I recommend using CSS for readability and only jump to XPath when I have to have specific functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd go about doing this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

XML = <<EOT
<comic>
  <mainsection>
    <credits>
      <credit>
        <role id="dfWriter">Writer</role>
        <person>
          <displayname>Will Pfeifer</displayname>
        </person>
      </credit>
      <credit>
        <role id="dfWriter">Writer</role>
        <person>
          <displayname>John Byrne</displayname>
        </person>
      </credit>
      <credit>
        <role id="dfPenciler">Penciller</role>
        <person>
          <displayname>John Byrne</displayname>
        </person>
      </credit>
    </credits>
  </mainsection>
</comic>
EOT

doc = Nokogiri::XML(XML)

writers = doc.search("credits role[id='dfWriter']").map { |w| w.parent.at('displayname').text }
pencilers = doc.search("credits role[id='dfPenciler']").map { |n| n.parent.at('displayname').text }

puts "Writer(s): %s" % writers.join(', ')
puts "Penciler(s): %s" % pencilers.join(', ')

# >> Writer(s): Will Pfeifer, John Byrne
# >> Penciler(s): John Byrne
```

Which, when run, outputs:

```
# >> Writer(s): Will Pfeifer, John Byrne
# >> Penciler(s): John Byrne
```

This:

```
writers = doc.search("credits role[id='dfWriter']").map { |w| w.parent.at('displayname').text }
pencilers = doc.search("credits role[id='dfPenciler']").map { |n| n.parent.at('displayname').text }
```

could be DRY'd to:

```
writers, pencilers = %w(dfWriter dfPenciler).map { |s|
  doc.search("credits role[id='#{s}']").map { |w| w.parent.at('displayname').text }
}
```

I used CSS for readability, and `at`, which returns a Node, when I want the text instead of `xpath`, which returns a NodeSet.

That distinction between using `text` on a NodeSet versus a Node is extremely important. Consider this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = <<EOT
<root>
  <displayname>Will Pfeifer</displayname>
  <displayname>John Byrne</displayname>
  <displayname>John Byrne</displayname>
</root>
EOT

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
doc.search('displayname').class # => Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet
doc.search('displayname').text # => "Will PfeiferJohn ByrneJohn Byrne"

doc.at('displayname').class # => Nokogiri::XML::Element
doc.at('displayname').text # => "Will Pfeifer"
```

If you want all the text for a NodeSet in a easily usable form then extract it from each node:

```
doc.search('displayname').map(&:text) # => ["Will Pfeifer", "John Byrne", "John Byrne"]
```